# Cakephp Select foreign key and order by name!

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I can get drop downs from foreign keys but how to sort them by name instead of id.

Adding 'order' => 'Country.name asc' in belongsTo model doesn't work, or I'm missing something!!!

e.g. Choose country,  state, city, and those to be sorted by name, instead of id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you scaffolding? If not should have a call similar to

```
$this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
```

in your controller simply add the sort condition to the find call e.g.

```
$this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list',array('order'=>'Group.name desc')));
```

Comment: As scaffold generates $this->set('groups', $this->paginate()); should I put this as third param, or...

also I have more than one drop box, and I need them to be in Add and Edit Action not on list (index).

Comment: Sorry I thought you were getting a drop down, I assumed you were on an add/edit form?

Comment: A baked index page should be just that and have CRUD options

A baked modification action should populate a drop down as I described in my answer. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: ok! Adding a user you have a Country_id, State_id, City_id which are from coutries table, ...  and default it will list as dropdown ordered by id and I want them to be ordered by name since countries are not added on db by name. eg. 1 => USA, 2 => Germany, 3=> France, 4 => Egypt .. and I want them to be in alphabetic order. 

like echo $this->Form->input('country_id'); should get them by name.

Comment: You where right, I just missed 

$countries = $this->User->County->find('list');

On edit action.